# How to enumerate a List containing many elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

This is my code:

```
public static class Authorisation
{
    public static List<PermissionMatrix> GetMatrixData()
    {
        List<PermissionMatrix> matrixList = new List<PermissionMatrix>()
        {
             new PermissionMatrix()
                {
                   ActorName= "SubmitterUser",
                   Moduledata = new List<Module>()
                    {
                         new Module()
                         {
                              moduleName= ModuleName.GeneralFormModule,
                               rights=AccessRights.Edit
                         },
                         new Module()
                         {
                              moduleName=ModuleName.AttachmentsModule,
                               rights=AccessRights.Edit
                         },
                         new Module()
                         {
                              moduleName= ModuleName.ProcurementModule,
                               rights= AccessRights.Edit
                         },
                         new Module()
                         {
                              moduleName= ModuleName.SupplierModule,
                               rights=AccessRights.Edit
                         },
                         new Module()
                         {
                              moduleName= ModuleName.DataPrivacyModule,
                               rights=AccessRights.Edit
                         },
                         new Module()
                         {
                              moduleName=ModuleName.SecurityModule,
                               rights=AccessRights.Edit
                         },
                         new Module()
                         {
                              moduleName = ModuleName.SecurityModuleUserComments,
                              rights = AccessRights.Edit
                         },
                         new Module()
                         {
                              moduleName= ModuleName.SecurityModuleRiskLikelihood,
                              rights =AccessRights.Edit
                         },
                         new Module()
                         {
                             moduleName= ModuleName.SecurityModuleRiskSeverity,
                             rights = AccessRights.Edit
                         },
                         new Module()
                         {
                             moduleName = ModuleName.SecurityModuleRiskYesNo,
                             rights = AccessRights.Edit
                         },
                         new Module()
                         {
                             moduleName = ModuleName.SecurityModuleSecurityComments,
                             rights = AccessRights.ReadOnly
                         }

                    }
                 },
              
                 },

        };
        return matrixList;

    }
}
public class PermissionMatrix
{
    public String? ActorName;
    public List<Module>? Moduledata;

}

public class Module
{
    public ModuleName? moduleName;
    public AccessRights? rights;
}

public enum ModuleName
{
    GeneralFormModule,
    AttachmentsModule,
    ProcurementModule,
    SupplierModule,
    DataPrivacyModule,
    SecurityModule,
    SecurityModuleRiskYesNo,
    SecurityModuleRiskSeverity,
    SecurityModuleRiskLikelihood,
    SecurityModuleUserComments,
    SecurityModuleSecurityComments

}

public enum AccessRights
{
    Show = 0,
    ReadOnly = 1,
    Edit = 2

}
```

Now I have to write a function which will pass the actorName and ModuleName and I want to get the permission back from the function.

I used extensionmethod like this.

```
 public static class PermissionExtensions
    {
        public static PermissionMatrix GetAllbyUserName(this IList<PermissionMatrix> coordinates, string user)
        {
           

            return coordinates.First(c => String.Equals(c.ActorName, user, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
        }

        public static AccessRights GetAccessPermissionsByUserandModuleName(this IList<PermissionMatrix> coordinates, string user, ModuleName)
        {
            //return ?

           
        }


    }
```

I tried putting  extension methods
**GetAllbyUserName** - I was able to write the function but for
**GetAccessPermissionsByUserandModuleName** - How to write a concise function ?

Comment: What's an "enumerator function"? Do you mean an iterator?

Comment: Can you reduce the 100s of lines defining modules to the bare minimum? Makes answering the question a lot easier. Also, I don't see an extension method in the posted code.

Comment: There's way too much code there. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then edit your question accordingly. Also, you need to provide a specific problem description. "I want to do X" is not a problem. It's not for us to just write your code for you. You need to show us what you've tried and explain how it doesn't meet your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a warning: you are using `Enumerable.First` which throws an exception if there's no matching `PermissionMatrix`. You should use `FirstOrDefault` which returns the default value(`null`).

Also note that i changed the return type of your extension method to `AccessRights?` since it's possible that no one matches, so you have to return `Nullable<AccessRights>`:

```
public static AccessRights? GetAccessPermissionsByUserandModuleName(this IList<PermissionMatrix> coordinates, string user, ModuleName module)
{
    return coordinates
        .FirstOrDefault(c => string.Equals(c?.ActorName, user, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))?
        .Moduledata?
        .Where(m => m.moduleName == module)
        .Select(m => m.rights)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: is it ? or ! to avoid null references?

Comment: @Venkat: It's `?`. Also don't confuse [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) of C#8 with the old [Null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) of C#6 which i'm using here. The nullable value types(`AccessRights?`) are even older(C#2).

Comment: This only worked. I had to replace ? with !.FirstOrDefault(c => string.Equals(c?.ActorName, user, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))!
       .Moduledata!
       .Where(m => m.moduleName == modulename)
       .Select(m => m.rights)
       .FirstOrDefault();